# How to print the returned message content from the stored procedure in golang

Tags: sql, go

How to print the returned message content from the stored procedure in golang

```
CREATE PROCEDURE AddNumbers
    @Number1 INT,
    @Number2 INT
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT @Number1 + @Number2 AS Result
END
```

If the normal execution is successful, the command will be printed successfully or other return information.

But when I use golang, I can only print the result list, but not the message list.

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "database/sql"
    "fmt"
    "log"

    _ "github.com/denisenkom/go-mssqldb"
)

func main() {
    connString := "server=127.0.0.1;user id=sa;password=P@ssw0rd;database=msdb;"
    db, err := sql.Open("mssql", connString)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer db.Close()

    ctx := context.Background()

    var message string
    err = db.QueryRowContext(ctx, "select @@version;").Scan(&message)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("failed to execute command: ", err)
    }

    fmt.Println("Message:", message)
}
```

How to print the returned message？

I have tried many ways of writing but none of them worked, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide the arguments and execute the stored procedure in the query:

```golang
number1 := 1
number2 := 2

var message string
db.QueryRowContext(ctx,
    "EXEC AddNumbers @Number1 = :number1, @Number2 = :number2", 
    sql.Named("number1", number1),
    sql.Named("number2", number2)
).Scan(&message)
fmt.Println("Message:", message)
```

```
Message: 3
```